# Matching only a unicode letter in Python re

Tags: python, regex, unicode, character-properties

I have a string from which i want to extract 3 groups:

```
'19 janvier 2012' -> '19', 'janvier', '2012'
```

Month name could contain non ASCII characters, so `[A-Za-z]` does not work for me:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(ur'(\d{,2}) ([A-Za-z]+) (\d{4})', u'20 janvier 2012', re.UNICODE).groups()
(u'20', u'janvier', u'2012')
>>> re.search(ur'(\d{,2}) ([A-Za-z]+) (\d{4})', u'20 février 2012', re.UNICODE).groups()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
>>>
```

I could use `\w` but it matches digits and underscore:

```
>>> re.search(ur'(\w+)', u'février', re.UNICODE).groups()
(u'f\xe9vrier',)
>>> re.search(ur'(\w+)', u'fé_q23vrier', re.UNICODE).groups()
(u'f\xe9_q23vrier',)
>>>
```

I tried to use [[:alpha:]](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#class), but it's not working:

```
>>> re.search(ur'[:alpha:]+', u'février', re.UNICODE).groups()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
>>>
```

If i could somehow match `\w` without `[_0-9]`, but i don't know how. And even if i find out how to do this, is there a ready shortcut like `[:alpha:]` which works in Python?

Comment: As for `[:alpha:]`, this only works inside a character class, so the correct regex would be `[[:alpha:]]+`, but Python doesn't support these anyway.

Comment: Why not simply call .split() on the string?

Comment: fyi `\w` already matches unicode see `For Unicode (str) patterns:
Matches Unicode word characters; this includes most characters that can be part of a word in any language, as well as numbers and the underscore. 
If the ASCII flag is used, only [a-zA-Z0-9_] is matched.`  ref https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html though idk if we need the `re.UNICODE` flag.

Comment: do we really need the `re.UNICODE` flag? The docs seem to imply it already works for unicode: `Both patterns and strings to be searched can be Unicode strings (str) as well as 8-bit strings (bytes).` correct me if I am wrong. Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: @CharlieParker probably this question was asked during Python 2 era.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can construct a new character class:

```
[^\W\d_]
```

instead of `\w`. Translated into English, it means "Any character that is not a non-alphanumeric character (`[^\W]` is the same as `\w`), but that is also not a digit and not an underscore".

Therefore, it will only allow Unicode letters.

Comment: I already recognized that `\p{L}` is not supported, so your solution is the way to go +1.

Comment: to include ``-`` in any regex character class, just put it at end (or beginning): ``[^\W\d_-]`` for this example.

Comment: @RichVel: That will *forbid* a minus sign.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - Yes, I didn't read that comment well enough...  one solution is to use regex alternation, e.g. something like this (not tested): ``([^\W\d_]|-)``

Comment: do we really need the `re.UNICODE` flag? The docs seem to imply it already works for unicode: `Both patterns and strings to be searched can be Unicode strings (str) as well as 8-bit strings (bytes).` correct me if I am wrong. Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: You're right, in Python 3 it's redundant. 2012, when this answer was written, Python 2 was still dominant, but I guess an edit is in order now :)