# What Python regex matches all alphabet characters but no numbers? [unicode aware]

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for the equivalent of `[\w]&&[^\d]` (Of course && is not a regex operator).
The regex needs to match ONLY words made up of UTF8 "alphabet" characters. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: NEVER perform regexs on encoded text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923949/matching-only-a-unicode-letter-in-python-re

Comment: Are you talking about the English alphabet? Then the answers [a-zA-Z] below will suffice. Otherwise you're in for a treat...

Comment: "NEVER perform regexs on encoded text." This for internationalized URL matching. Not longform text.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams "NEVER perform regexs on encoded text." How come there is an re.UNICODE flag then? I guess things break for you when you're not using that flag.

Comment: @bpj: `re.UNICODE` doesn't make `re` work on encoded text, it makes various special sequences match non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`regex`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) supports Unicode properties, which means that you can use `\p{L}` with it.

Answer (score 1):

As Ignacio pointed out `[a-zA-Z]` would not match Unicode characters, and there is no character class predefined for all Unicode characters, you may want to use something similar to the following, which would be simple and straightforward

```
re.findall("(["+string.letters+"])+",st)
```

Please note, string.letters is locale dependent and unless you want to switch the local, which you can off-course do with `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_CTYPE, code)`, this should work as a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, there isn't a regex that matches all letters but not digits or underscores.

You could use `\w` and then check to see if the matches are letters using the code point properties:

```
def isletter(c):
    return unicodedata.category(c).startswith('L')
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about regex, but for unicode you might be able to make use of the `uncodedata` module; specifically the [`unicodedata.category()`](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html) function

Answer (score -6):

Use [a-zA-Z] to match all the alphabet characters.

Comment: Incorrect. This will miss "あ".

Comment: That's not a alphabet character.

Comment: Yes it is. It's just not an English alphabet character.

Comment: "éléphant" : the 'é' wouldn't match.