# get the portion of a string between two positions with php

Tags: php

I have a string like `"some words 12345cm some more words"`

and I want to extract the `12345cm` bit from that string. So I get the position of the first number:

```
$position_of_first_number = strcspn( "some words 12345cm some more words" , '0123456789' );
```

Then the position of the first space after `$position_of_first_number`

```
$position_of_space_after_numbers = strpos("some words 12345cm some more words", " ", $position_of_first_number);
```

Then I want to have a function which return the portion of the string between `$position_of_first_number` and `$position_of_space_after_numbers`.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [substr function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php). Note that it takes a starting position and a *length*, which you can calculate as the difference between the start and end positions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for a **pattern** like *blank-digits-letters-blank*, I would recommend a regular expression using [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$s = "some words 12345cm some more words";
preg_match("/\s(?P<result>\d+[^\W\d_]+)\s/", $s, $matches);
echo $matches["result"];

12345cm
```

**Explaining the pattern**:

- `"/.../"` limits the pattern in PHP
- `\s` matches any whitespace character
- `(?P<name>...)` names the following pattern
- `\d+` matches 1 or more digits
- `[^\W\d_]+` matches 1 or more Unicode-letters (i.e. any character that is not a non-alphanumeric character; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8923988/3104974))